# Как убрать предупреждение после обновления php до версии 5.6?

Tags: php, debian

После обновления PHP 5.4 ---> PHP 5.6 стало выскакивать предупреждение:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/pecl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pecl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

[image: Скрин с ошибкой]

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас просто нет pecl.so в каталоге в котором его пытаются найти. видимо в php.ini надо указать правильный путь и/или собрать pecl явно для вашей новой версии php

Comment: или просто отключить его, если он вам не нужен

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Закомментировал подключение в файле /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pecl.ini :  ;extension=pecl.so     Для меня  странно что  этот файл вообще появился и то что раз уж появился не создался pecl.so в соответствующем каталоге